# Checklist of steps to config and test replication on ms sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server

We are preparing to implement transactional replication between two of our sql servers.

The server that will act as the publisher and distributor is an x64 sql server 2005 standard. The subscriber is an x64 sql server 2008 sp1 enterprise.

Does anyone have a checklist of things information that we need to configure this?

I would also like to see if anyone has any scripts to verify that things are working correctly

Answer (score 1):

Just run through the wizard, that will get everything setup.

Then look at the distribution monitor in SQL Management studio (by right clicking on the publication under the replication folder in SQL Management Studio).  It'll tell you how much data is being moved, and how backlogged the replication is (if it is).  It'll also allow you to drop a test message into the replication process to see how long it takes to replicate.